# Codeigniter controller variable lost after change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, progress-bar

I have a simple jquery progress bar that should get a variable from Codeigniter controller and print it on screen. 
The problem is that when a function changes that variable, the result is lost and so the progress bar shows 0.

Here's my code:

```
class Emails extends CI_Controller {

public $p;
...

public function test()
{
    for ($i=0; $i < 1000000; $i++)
    { 
        $this->setprogress($i);
    }
}
public function setprogress($value)
    {
        $this->p = intval($value); 
}

public function progress()
{
    print $this->p;
}
```

In jquery

```
function getProgress(){
    $.get('<?=site_url("/emails/progress"); ?>', function(data) {
        percent = (parseInt(data));
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get('<?=site_url("/emails/test"); ?>', function(parsing) {});
    interval = setInterval(getProgress, 100);
});
```

The progress variable always comes back empty (NaN).
Any suggestions?
Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: With this code i can't really see where is the problem, you are just printing $this->p, but you are not setting it, you are getting /emails/progress, but i don't see where do you set the variable $this->p; Just do $this->p = 1;  before the print $this->p; just to debug it

Comment: On the DOMReady I call via ajax the function test() which sets $this->p according to the for cycle in it.

Comment: Everytime you do a ajax call it will initialize your "controller"; 2 ajax calls = 2 requests, save the data to the CI cache, Session,DB , File w/e or change your design!

Comment: Ok this is useful information. Thanks!
Do you maybe have any suggestion how can i change it without calling the test function over and over again?

Comment: I don't have enough information of your code, but i don't really think you have much better options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the proper solution. Thanks to [Jorge Faianca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1683134/jorge-faianca) for the big hint

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('session');
}

public function test()
{
    for ($i=0; $i < 100; $i++) { 
        $this->setprogress($i);
    }
}

function setprogress($value)
{
    $this->session->set_userdata('progress', intval($value)); 
}

public function progress()
{
    print $this->session->userdata('progress'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As i was explaining in the comment,you can do this, this way. ( use the session library from Code Igniter instead of the native one )

```
public function test()
{
    for ($i=0; $i < 1000000; $i++)
    { 
        $this->setprogress($i);
    }
}
public function setprogress($value)
{
     $_SESSION['progress'] = intval($value); 
}

public function progress()
{
    echo $_SESSION['progress'];
}
```

Comment: It's CodeIgniter mate. I'm pretty sure it already does that for you.

Comment: I'm not sure, but CodeIgniter doesn't use native sessions. They use totally a different mechanism. You're not using their session library, you're using the native sessions, so I believe you do have to.

Comment: I guess you are right, Just use the Session from CI, doesn't matter, it was just an example.

Comment: Thank Jorge, nice solution.
All the others, please refer to my last post for the solution working in Codeingniter